# Spring MVC get request composite key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a table called StudentLesson with a primary Composite Key StudentLessonPk which is made up of Student_id and Lesson_id. I would like to get the student lessons by id but of course I cannot pass an object to a path variable.
I am very new to spring JPA any help is much appreciated. My code for reference:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class StudentLessonPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5611658036387185008L;

    @Column(name = "Student_Id")
    private String Student_Id;

    @Column(name = "Lesson_Id")
    private String Lesson_Id;


    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public String getStudent_Id() {
        return Student_Id;
    }

    public void setStudent_Id(String student_Id) {
        Student_Id = student_Id;
    }

    public String getLesson_Id() {
        return Lesson_Id;
    }

    public void setLesson_Id(String lesson_Id) {
        Lesson_Id = lesson_Id;
    }
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public StudentLessonPK(String student_Id, String lesson_Id) {
        super();
        Student_Id = student_Id;
        Lesson_Id = lesson_Id;
    }

    public StudentLessonPK(){

    }


}
```

my incorrect Get Request in my controller: I would like to achieve something like /studentslesson/{studentid}/{lessonid}

```
@RequestMapping(value="/studentslesson/{StudentLessonPK}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StudentLesson StudentLessonById(@PathVariable StudentLessonPK id) {
        return StudentLessonService.getStudentLesson(id);
    }
```

my StudentLesson Service class:

```
public StudentLesson getStudentLesson(StudentLessonPK id) {
        Optional<StudentLesson> optionalStudentLesson = studentLessonRepository.findById(id);
        if(optionalStudentLesson.isPresent()) {
            return optionalStudentLesson.get();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My repository:

```
    public interface StudentLessonRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentLesson, StudentLessonPK> {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you can define studentId and lessonId as two different path parameters, construct a StudentLessonPK object from the two parameters and then pass it to StudentLessonService.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/studentslesson/{studentId}/{lessonId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public StudentLesson StudentLessonById(@PathVariable String studentId, @PathVariable String lessonId) {
    StudentLessonPK id = new StudentLessonPK(studentId, lessonId);
    return StudentLessonService.getStudentLesson(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add the correct params  and all was well. @RequestMapping(value="/studentslesson/{Student_Id}/{Lesson_Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public StudentLesson StudentLessonById(@PathVariable String Student_Id, @PathVariable String Lesson_Id) {
     StudentLessonPK id = new StudentLessonPK(Student_Id, Lesson_Id);
     return studentLessonService.getStudentLesson(id);
 }